# Call a controller from the jsp page

Tags: java, spring

1. I have a jsp page which shows a hyperlink. I want that hyperlink to call the controller and than some method in that controller. How can i accomplish this thing in my jsp page?
2. Is there any secure method to pass some parameters to that controller?

Comment: What do you mean by a controller? a Servlet?

Comment: Yeah a servlet. Controller in spring.

Comment: refer [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-tutorials/)

Comment: Spring uses request mappings to map a URL to a controller/controller method. You would use https if you need to secure the data passed to that method. What have you tried and what were the problems?

Comment: Are you doing this from scratch or is the `DispatcherServlet` already setup and working?

Answer (score 0):

In a JSP you will define hyperlink as follows:

```
<a href="/test">Link</a>
```

and in your web.xml you should specify the servlet URL as follows

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And this will give call to your servlet on clicking the link..Then from that servlet you can call your own method or do whatever you want!

Hope this helps

Comment: He's talking about Java class annotated with Spring `@Controller`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this....one way which I have implemented is that you have a central controller which would be the only controller called. This controller would load all other controllers based on the url resolving the controller name from the url....based on some predefined convention.....once the controller name is resolved..it would again using a predefined convention determine which method of the controller to call....once both are defined....instantiate the controller and invoke the method through reflection

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand Spring , each controller is associated with a `@RequestMapping` annotation. If you define :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/controller1")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String gohome()
    {       
        return "home-1";

    }
```

And

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/controller2")
public class HomeControllerb {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String gohome()
    {       
        return "home-2";

    }
```

And you hit the endpoint `/controller1/home` you will indeed load the `gohome()` method from the controller 1 as defined and load the file `home-1.jsp`